# Cleaning up after "docker-compose down" (removing docker containers after parent container shuts down)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'am creating docker containers dynamically using a generator container opened via docker-compose
I want to clean up all the child containers after I shut down the generator container (docker-compose down).

I have a script cleanup.sh that I run as ENTRYPOINT (ENTRYPOINT [ "cleanup.sh" ]) in my Dockerfile

cleanup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

#Define cleanup procedure
cleanup() {
    echo "Container stopped, performing cleanup..."
}

#Trap SIGTERM
trap 'cleanup' SIGTERM

#Execute a command
"${@}" &
echo "Stopping docker containers"
docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q  -f "name=test_")
docker rm $(sudo docker ps -a -q  -f "name=test_")

#Wait
wait $!
```

The Dockerfile that uses the cleaning script as ENTRYPOINT:

```
FROM python:3.10
ENTRYPOINT [ "docker/docker-files/generator/cleanup.sh" ]
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .


RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt


RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq tzdata ca-certificates curl gnupg sudo && \
    ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Poland /etc/localtime && \
    dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata && \ 
    curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com | sh
        
WORKDIR /opt/app/
COPY . /opt/app/

CMD ["python", "scripts/generator.py"]
```

The docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  generator:
    image: generator
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/docker-files/generator/Dockerfile
    tty: true
    working_dir: /opt/app/
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: generator
      LOG_LINES: 9999:-9999
    restart: always
    networks:
      in-network:
        aliases:
          - generator
```

The correct operation should be as follows: after running the **docker-compose up** command, the generator container creates child containers. After running the **docker-compose down** command, the generator container removes its child containers and closes itself.

The current operation works as follows: after running the **docker-compose up** command, the generator container creates child containers (this part works correctly).  After running the **docker-compose down** command, the generator container closes itself and leaves the child containers running. But after rerunning the **docker-compose up** and **docker-compose down** commands it removes only the children that the previous generator container created.

So the cleaning up command only works on containers that were running before the **docker-compose up** command was executed. Is there a solution for my issue ? Maybe someone has done something similar and knows what I've done wrong

Comment: Docker doesn't have any notion of "parent" or "child" containers.  If you are using the Docker socket to dynamically create containers, your application needs to keep track of them and your application needs to delete them.  Docker has nothing to help with this workflow.  Setting up a shutdown hook in your application would be a good first step.

Comment: @DavidMaze I know that docker does not have "parent" or "child" thats why i created my own script which should run when the so called "parent" is shutting down. But the script does not see any containers that were created after the "parend" was created

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include some details, like how you're keeping track of the containers you've created, or what sort of shutdown hook you've tried to write?  (`docker-compose down` will never do this on its own.)  Do you actually need to dynamically create containers, or can you push work out to a longer-running worker container?

Comment: To add to what @DavidMaze is saying, it would be good to know how you're currently interacting with docker on the host machine at all as you'd have to mount the socket into the "parent" container

Comment: I have updated the question. To show the docker-compose.yml file and the Dockerfile. I'm running multiple observers that should be generated dynamically because I don't know how many containers I have to run. The generator script in an interval checks the observers creates new containers or deletes unused containers if needed. The script is working fine but the problem is when i wont to stop the "parent" container. The script does not see the containers that the "parent" containers created. The observers are left intact.

Comment: When i start the "parent" container again and stop it, the previous generated observer will be removed